# tornado-redis connection unixsocket

Tags: python, redis, tornado-redis

could anyone explain how to connect to redis using unixsockets.

```
redis_conn = tornadoredis.Client('hostname', 'port')
redis_conn.connect()
```

I do not have hostname or port for redis-server,  I commented bind lines in it config, and cofiguired it to use socket:

```
unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 755
```

Can you please explin it to me ot give me the link to documents please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here in code https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis/blob/master/tornadoredis/connection.py:
It seams it should work something like:

```
redis_conn = tornadoredis.Client(unix_socket_path='/var/run/redis/redis.sock')
redis_conn.connect()
```